# How can I scratch lottery tickets?

Tags: substitute-tool

So here's the thing. I tend to keep my nails trimmed pretty short. I don't often have coins in my wallet. Those were always the top two ways to scratch off lottery tickets that I've been told.

Problem is, I find myself in possession of a scratch ticket, and I want to know if I've won the big money.

What are some things in my office I can use? I've tried a paperclip, and a pen lid. Neither were all that effective.

Comment: @AshleyNunn: most of them.

Comment: You can use coins, keys, shopping cart coins, a losing ticket, credit card (as suggested), rubbing your finger, scratch just the bottom-most part, wish the codebar (depends on the system)... There's tons!

Comment: Save your money and [don't buy lottery tickets](http://www.businessinsider.com/lottery-is-a-tax-on-the-poor-2012-4?op=1), problem solved.

Comment: -1 Stop gambling!

Comment: @KiranLinsuain but gambling is not a problem if you only allot yourself a certain amount to spend that you don't go over. It's like any type of entertainment, do it in moderation and don't blow all your money on it.

Comment: @KiranLinsuain We get scratch tickets as a cherry on top of the holiday bonus.  There's really no need to downvote because of your personal preference.  Also, given that OP does not have a host of card scratching tools, I think that it's safe to assume he/she doesn't often buy therm.

Comment: @Carl That makes sense, I am very sorry. If OP changes a character, I will undo downvote and upvote.

Comment: @KiranLinsuain click the down button again

Comment: I cannot change my vote unless the question is edited, I don't know why that restriction is there.

Comment: @AdamZuckerman Vote changed.

Comment: @KiranLinsuain You may want to read this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75477/289125 and also, said by Jeff Atwood himself: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/18046/289125

Comment: Even if you don't have coins, don't the places you buy tickets from typically have a "need a penny" bowl or something that you could borrow one from? I also can't imagine a tool that would be much easier to carry than a coin for scratching a ticket off..

Comment: Some places will just scan the card to see if it won regardless of whether it's scratched.  But I've never tried that myself.

Comment: @Bobson Here you have to scratch off a barcode sort of thing to use the scanner that lets you know if it's a winning ticket, so either way, I need to scratch something.

Comment: I won't post this as answer because I don't know if it works or maybe even is poisonous but maybe you can use your teeth. It's also not very hygienic and looks stupid if anyone sees you. But if you really don't have a single object with you you could give that a try

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Any type of plastic card may work, you probably have one in your wallet, so fairly accessible.
[image]

Comment: The credit card totally worked.

Comment: Please limit your answer to just one solution. By having multiple solutions in one answer, if your answer is marked as accepted, the rest of us have no way to know which solution was the one that worked. Recommended reading: [Lifehacks Manifesto](http://meta.lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/2431/a-lifehacks-manifesto)

Comment: @AdamZuckerman in this case, the asker said which worked. should i next time post 4 different answers?

Comment: Yes, please do that.

Comment: I used my card yesterday to scratch one :D Worked fine but to be honest it's quite annoying due to it's 'bendy-ness' it doesn't scratch the card very effectively and takes longer to do

Comment: use one of the corners, this allows you to firmly hold on to the majority of the card, that way "bendy-ness" can be greatly reduced, also scratch in an angle @Arazio

Comment: Does anyone else see the irony in using a credit card to further your lottery pursuits?

Comment: @JoelB isn't it great?

Answer (score 11):

Also if you are a into music you may have one of these in your pocket that can do the trick. 
[image]

Answer (score 9):

You can use the edge of a key.  Turn the key so that the sharpest edge along a flat edge is used to scrape the scratch area.

I couldn't find a picture, but it is the same technique you would use when using a coin to scratch a card.

Comment: a friend tried that once and it actually took off the ink too

Comment: Agreed with Dragon; you scratch it all right, but you have to be careful not to damage it

Answer (score 5):

You can use one of these scratch off tools.
[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: I kinda feel like I need one of these. Wonder where I'd find one.

Comment: @AshleyNunn can probably find something similar to it on amazon. or possibly at like a gas station market or something

Comment: @AshleyNunn if you feel like you need one of these, you might wanna start going to meetings.

Comment: @KiranLinsuain isnt that localized to the united states?

Answer (score 5):

I carry one of these on my keychain.

[image]

I don't play the lottery, but it is great for scratching off the grey stuff on the backs of prepaid cards.

Comment: Lottery tickets tend to be more fragile than hard plastic prepaid cards. I believe they will sometimes be voided if you accidentally puncture the ticket.

Comment: You would have to be beasting it.  This is pretty dull, nowhere near as sharp as a knife or a screwdriver.

Answer (score 5):

also if you carry a nail file like this
[image]
you can use the pointed tip or the edge to scratch it off.

Comment: The idea is good, but it is not airplane safe, if I know correctly. Just saying :)

Answer (score 5):

I thought the default that everyone used was a quarter. Or any coin with a rough edge.

Comment: In my question, I mention I rarely have coins.

Comment: @AshleyNunn sorry, I skimmed the question and missed that part

Comment: @Kevin No worries, it happens. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use your pants' zipper or button.

Case in point, you are supposedly wearing some of these clothes when being outside. So you can immediately scratch your ticket in the store.

Comment: And just how am I supposed to angle myself to scratch particular areas of the card? This strikes me as a highly difficult and impractical solution.

Comment: @AshleyNunn Agreed that pants zipper is pretty impractical, it's a hard angle to use and even if you can it will look quite weird. However, a jacket zipper would probably work pretty well!

Answer (score 1):

Do you have hot drink making facilities? A teaspoon would work pretty well. A USB connector would work too, or a stapler if you can get it at the right angle. Other things in sight of my desk - ruler, coaster, bulldog clip and old cd/dvds

Answer (score 1):

A metal collar stay!  a few clean swipes and all of the scratching cratching is done

[image: this is what i used]
<sub>(source: [josbank.com](https://scene7.josbank.com/is/image/JosBank/8732_000_main?iv=P9yaj0&wid=1576&hei=1820&fit=fit,1))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Do you carry a penknife?

You could use the knife, or bottle opener parts pretty easily.

Comment: I don't, but I keep thinking that I should. It feels like it might be useful.

Comment: @AshleyNunn I have a wallet ninja (google it) and it's awesome. Supprising how often I actually use it.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time I used any parts of the ball pen like the bottom part of it. If you are lucky to have the cap of the ball pen it can effectively scratch your lottery ticket.

I suggest the pen because it is always available in almost every places, you can borrow one if you can't find any.

Answer (score 0):

I found this thing on eBay that works great on my bingo scratch off game's and also on big scratch area's on other ticket games. I think it's called ezscratch,under scratch tools.Its blade is different than most of those others and it came on A keychain. I actually use it for more then lottery tickets.You got to check it out.Hope I helped you. No more broken nails.