# How do I avoid or otherwise minimize the mess of dust from scratching a game currency card?

Tags: dust

Ash already asked a question about how to do the scratching on lottery tickets, which are quite similar to game currency cards. However, I have a different problem when scratching my Steam wallet cards: scratching cards like this tends to make a lot of dust of whatever it is they paint on there. This dust sticks to everything: whatever you use to scratch the card, the card itself, your fingers, the surface you're scratching the card on and who knows what else. It's generally also hard to clean off since on most surfaces you're just going to spread it instead of pick it up.

How do I avoid or minimize this mess of dust?

Comment: Ash' question: https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/10963/how-can-i-scratch-lottery-tickets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never found this to be a problem. Do the scratching over a trash can. Brush the dust off the card and into the bin.

Answer (score 0):

We found out accidentally that rubbing alcohol on cotton ball takes it off with no mess…